# timer doesnt write time inside the input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Problems.

First is, I wrote an JS, to become my time from a JSON formated output.

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/status",
            processData: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                var status = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                /* Status information from Stream and Record */
                $("input[id='streamStatus']").val(status.stream[0]);
                $("input[id='recordStatus']").val(status.record[0]);
                $("input[id='totalUsb']").val(status.storage[1] + "MB");
                $("input[id='freeUsb']").val(status.storage[2] + "MB");


                if (status.record[1] == "-1") {
                    if (status.record[1] < 60) {
                        $("#recordDuration").text(status.record[1] + "s" + " (start)");
                    } else if (status.record[1] < 3600) {
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.record[1] / 60);
                        var second = status.record[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        $("#recordDuration").text(minute + ":" + second + " (start)");
                    } else {
                        var hour = Math.floor(status.record[1] / 3600);
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.record[1] / 60) - hour * 60;
                        if (minute < 10) {
                            minute = "0" + minute;
                        }
                        var second = status.record[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        if (hour > 99) {
                            $("#recordDuration").text(hour + "h (start)");
                        } else {
                            $("#recordDuration").text(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " (start)");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (status.stream[1] > 0) {
                    if (status.stream[1] == -1) {
                        $("#recordDuration").text("infinite (no stop)");
                    }
                    else if (status.time < 60) {
                        $("#recordDuration").text(status.stream[1] + "s" + " (stop)");
                    } else if (status.stream[1] < 3600) {
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.stream[1] / 60);
                        var second = status.stream[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        $("#recordDuration").text(minute + ":" + second + " (stop)");
                    } else {
                        var hour = Math.floor(status.stream[1] / 3600);
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.stream[1] / 60) - hour * 60;
                        if (minute < 10) {
                            minute = "0" + minute;
                        }
                        var second = status.stream[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        if (hour > 99) {
                            $("#recordDuration").text(hour + "h (stop)");
                        } else {
                            $("#recordDuration").text(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " (stop)");
                        }
                    }

                    if (status.record[1] == 0) {
                        $("#recordDuration").text("stopped");
                    } else if (status.record[1] < 60) {
                        $("#recordDuration").text(status.record[1] + "s");
                    } else if (status.record < 3600) {
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.record[1] / 60);
                        var second = status.record[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        $("#recordDuration").text(minute + ":" + second);
                    } else {
                        var hour = Math.floor(status.record[1] / 3600);
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.record[1] / 60) - hour * 60;
                        if (minute < 10) {
                            minute = "0" + minute;
                        }
                        var second = status.record[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        $("#recordDuration").val(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
                    }
                    if (status.stream[1] == "0") {
                        $("#recordDuration").text("stopped");
                    } else if (status.stream[1] < 60) {
                        $("#recordDuration").text(status.stream[1] + "s");
                    } else if (status.stream[1] < 3600) {
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.stream[1] / 60);
                        var second = status.stream[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        $("#recordDuration").text(minute + ":" + second);
                    } else {
                        var hour = Math.floor(status.stream[1] / 3600);
                        var minute = Math.floor(status.stream[1] / 60) - hour * 60;
                        if (minute < 10) {
                            minute = "0" + minute;
                        }
                        var second = status.stream[1] % 60;
                        if (second < 10) {
                            second = "0" + second;
                        }
                        $("#recordDuration").val(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

I have 2 different counter, one is for the recording timer and another one for the streaming.
Both of them must be written in #recordDuration input box.
This is working so, when the one is started later as another one, the website must show the counter from the last started.

here is my HTML input box

```
<p style="margin-left: 10px; color:#0099FF" scope="row">duraction
                <input type="time" style="border: 0px; font: 14px/1.231 sans-serif" value="00:00:00" id="recordDuration"
                       readonly/></p>
```

Problem is, my counter on the Website, will start shown the right counter after 5 min.
Second problem, my counter doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: Input fields have .val() not .text() - change all occurrences of `$("#recordDuration").text(`  to `$("#recordDuration").val(` or change the input field to a div/span and then change the stray  `$("#recordDuration").val(` to `$("#recordDuration").text(` too

Comment: this helps, thank you.
But the Chrome problem is still alive

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no, it just show me in Chrome " --:-- "

Comment: Why `if (status.record[1] == "-1") {
                    if (status.record[1] < 60) {`
it does not make any sense

Comment: This also makes no logical sense `else if (status.stream[1] > 0) {
        if (status.stream[1] == -1) {`

Comment: Also `else if (status.record < 3600) {` does not make sense if status.record is an array - testing here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kgcfafcf/

Comment: sorry, I cant answer you question, the full code I didnt wrote alone.

Comment: From the code I cannot even guess what it is supposed to do. It is riddled with logical errors. At least provide us with an example of results that show the different situations. the fiddle I provided does not give any errors and it does put something in the div depending on the value of the record.

Comment: at the moment, its only work with the counter from stream:
http://gyazo.com/52a94076cd2c213ea26f1a15187b43fb
http://gyazo.com/bbeb20825b00cb06a74a4346e0cb8251

If stream is stopped, the counter will be not run, but it must, when record status is on - recording

Comment: The URLs you provide do not return any JSON that can be used to test the clock